# How to go to another route using <Redirect> on componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to redirect user to /login if he isn't authenticated.

To do so, I'm checking if the user is authenticated in `componentDidMount()` and if he isn't I'm redirecting him to `/login` using the `<Redirect to="/login"/>` balise.

The problem is that I have this error: `You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>`, despite the fact that I am in a `<BrowserRouter>`

Here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import MainPage from "./pages/main-page/main-page";
import LoginPage from "./pages/login-page/login-page";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/private-route";

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={MainPage}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
   );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my main-page.js

```
import React from 'react';
import authManager from "../../services/auth";
import Redirect from "react-router/modules/Redirect";


export default class MainPage extends React.Component{
    state = {
        loggedIn: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        authManager.isAuthenticate((res) => {
            if (res.data)
                this.setState({loggedIn: true})
        }).then()
    }

    render() {

        if (!this.state.loggedIn)
            return <Redirect to='/login'/>;

        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And here is my private-route.js

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from "react";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true'
            ? <Component {...props}/>
            : <Redirect to='/login'/>
    )} />
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code for works fine, the problem is that I'm importing the `<Redirect>` from `'react-router/modules/Redirect'` instead of using `'react-router-dom'`.

To make this code work you just have to replace in main-page.js:

`import Redirect from "react-router/modules/Redirect";`

to

`import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';`

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true'
            ? <Component {...props}/>
            : <Navigate to="/login" />
    )} />
);
```

Comment: you can use Navigate from react-router-dom